# Pandas: to.datetime() quesiton

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Date/Time in the following format:

10/01/21 04:49:43.75
MM/DD/YY HH/MM/SS.ms

I am trying to convert this from being an object to a datetime. I tried the following code but i am getting an error that it does not match the format. Any ideas?

```
df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], format = '%m%d%y %H%M%S%f')
```

[image]

Comment: Could U provide df['Date/Time'] ?

Comment: I have added a picture to my original question.

Comment: I mean, of course it doesn't match the format: `%m%d%y` doesn't contain slashes, but `10/01/21`, for example, does. Same thing with colons separating hours, minutes and seconds: the format `%H%M%S%f` doesn't have the colons

Comment: I have added them and it didnt work, then i deleted to post this question. that didnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try letting pandas infer the datetime format with:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Comment: ParserError: Unknown string format: 10/02/21 23:41:40.5,"10/2/21 11:41:40 PM Channel Failure" I am getting this error when doing that.

Comment: ok this doesnt look like a valid format: `10/2/21 11:41:40 PM Channel Failure` can you clean the data bit before parsing?

Comment: How would I go about that? I am new to Python and Pandas so still learning. My data has two columns, one is date/time the other pressure. I have already got the Pressure to register as a numeric, now Im wokring to get Date/Time to get the proper format

Comment: try with this `pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'].str.replace(r'^(.*PM|.*AM)(.*)', r"\1", regex=True), infer_datetime_format=True)` . Without knowing more about the data it's har to see how it needs to be cleaned